# Lists in Python last element

Tags: python

I am new to python and I tried this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.7,1.3,0.1)
print (x)
y = np.arange(0.6,1.3,0.1)
print (y)
```

The output was `[ 0.7  0.8  0.9  1.   1.1  1.2  1.3]` and `[ 0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.   1.1  1.2]`. Why in the first case 1.3 appears in the list and in the second case it doesn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to [rounding errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).  If you actually print the last element in `x` in it's full precision, you'll see that it is smaller than `1.3`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(0.7,1.3,0.1)
>>> 1.3 > x[-1]
True
>>> x[-1]
1.2999999999999998
```

Note, as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use `linspace` for these cases.:

Comment: Though rounding could be issue, I think documentation reference is better answer, because why the same rounding issue didn't occur in first example?

Comment: @Nambari -- Yeah, unless you're an IEEE 754 guru (which I'm not), it's hard to predict exactly how the rounding error will mess with you which is why I added a link to the docs and the relevant blurb to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`arange` is not suitable for floating point numbers:

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to [use linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) for these cases.

I'm not familiar with the internals of numpy, but my guess is that this is a side effect of floating point numbers not being exact (meaning that they can't exactly represent some values).

Answer (score 1):

See the numpy.arange documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> specifically "When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use `linspace` for these cases"